# incorrect register '%rbx' used with 'l' suffix

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm trying to compile this code under linux with gcc compiler :

```
static inline unsigned long get_current(void)
{
    unsigned long current;

    asm volatile (
    " movl %%esp, %%eax;"
    " andl %1, %%eax;"
    " movl (%%eax), %0;"
    : "=r" (current)
    : "i" (0xfffff000)
    );
    return current;
}
```

But i'm getting this error :

```
program.c: Assembler messages: program.c:455: Error: incorrect
register `%rbx' used with `l' suffix
```

what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, you're compiling for 64 bits. Try using gcc -m32 if it's not what you want, or use 64-bit registers (%esp makes no sense at all on x64).

Answer (score 4):

Whilst the above is sort of correct, I expect it's actually NOT the right solution. If you're compiling this for x86-64, you should use 64-bit operations for "get current".  (If the (kernel?) stack is still only 1 page, otherwise you'll want a different mask constant to calculate the bottom of the stack.)

```
asm volatile (
  " movq %1, %%rax \n"
  " andq %%rsp, %%rax;"         // discard the low 12 bits
  " movq (%%rax), %0;"
  : "=r" (current)
  : "i" (0xfffffffffffff000)
  : "rax"       // Remember to mark any temporary registers modified in "clobber"
    , "memory"  // and we read memory at an address that might hold a C object
);
```

If this memory location is never written with plain C, it might be safe to omit the `"memory"` clobber.

I rearranged the instructions, as you can't use 64-bit immediates with most instructions.  (Although *this* particular constant does fit in a signed 32-bit imm32 so `and $imm, %rax` would have been fine, but doing it this way might be more efficient since it avoids copying RSP before AND.  The constant doesn't fit in an imm8 so both ways have the same code size.)

Instead of clobbering RAX, you could have used `%0` as the temporary for rounding down the stack pointer down to the start of a 4k page.  Replace `%%rax` with `%0` everywhere in the template string, and remove the `"rax"` clobber.  Or just use inline asm to get `uintptr_t rsp`, and do the load part in C, like `*(volatile uinptr_t*)(rsp & -4096)`.

Comment: I'm too lazy to test, but this looks like the right answer for x86-64 code to me, because of the issue that in x86-64 Intel assembly you can't use full 64-bit immediates in any other instruction except `mov` (see [NASM manual: 11.2 Immediates and Displacements in 64-bit Mode](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdo11.html#section-11.2)). For 32-bit code Anton Kovalenko's answer is probably correct.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter what assembler you use, 64-bit constants aren't available - there is no option in the instruction encoding to do that. And I didn't test it either... ;)

Comment: It's possible to code this in a way that works for both 32bit and 64bit compiles on x86, see my answer.

Comment: You only need inline asm for one thing, and that's reading `%rsp`.  It's silly to use it this way.  But anyway, `0xfffffffffffff000` *does* fit in a sign-extended 32-bit immediate, so it's fine to use `movq` instead of `movabs`.  (But modern versions of GAS use the `mov r64, imm64` encoding for large constants if you use `movq`).  But anyway, you could instead ask for the mask input in the output register instead of as an immediate, and just return a pointer.  Also, this is maybe not safe because you don't tell the compiler about memory that you're reading; it could do dead-store elimination.

Answer (score 3):

I would code this like:

```
static inline unsigned long get_current(void)
{
    unsigned register long current asm("sp");

    asm volatile ("" : "=r"(current));

    return (current & ~ (unsigned long)0xfff);
}
```

This compiles both on 64bit and 32bit; creates the following code:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <get_current>:
   0:   48 89 e0                mov    %rsp,%rax
   3:   48 25 00 f0 ff ff       and    $0xfffffffffffff000,%rax
   9:   c3                      retq
```

respectively, for 32bit:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <get_current>:
   0:   89 e0                   mov    %esp,%eax
   2:   25 00 f0 ff ff          and    $0xfffff000,%eax
   7:   c3                      ret
```

One of the nifty things of gcc's inline assembler is the ability to bind variables to registers, and yes, as shown, it recognizes `sp` on x86.

**Edit:** oops ... just noticed gcc 3.4.5 creates funny code for the above - even at high optimization levels, where it normally eliminates the frame pointer on its own, the above source will make create a framepointer (for a non-static instantiation of the function). Explicit compile with `-fomit-frame-pointer` on gcc 3.4.5 or the use of gcc 4.x creates the correct code now shown (see posting history for what gcc 3.4.5 does).

Comment: The OP is dereferencing this masked value as a pointer and reading an `unsigned long` from the bottom of the current stack page.  You should use `uintptr_t` to read the stack pointer.  (And BTW, it might be better to use an actual `mov` instead of telling the compiler about a variable that's stored in SP.)